# Why Gmail shows "[Message clipped] View entire message" at the end of my emails?

Tags: email, gmail

I'm using Java to send emails but Gmail shows me "[Message clipped]  View entire message" at the end of the message. My email is around 20 characters (English letters), plain text, and there is no attachments. And there are no new lines. I've tried to add a new line at the end of the email but it didn't help.

Comment: Gmail combines emails with the same subject line into a single email in the inbox. Is that the problem?

Comment: No. There is no combination. I delete these email after I see them. Just now I have even deleted them from the trash folder. Still this last message has "[Message clipped]  View entire message".

Comment: Check the size of the headers. If nothing found, maybe try an HTML message.

Answer (score 0):

Clipping is caused by the sender including soft-hyphens `–` (e.g. `&shy;` or `&mdash;`) or other dash-like characters - it's nothing to do with the size of the message, and nothing you as a recipient can fix.

The reason is most likely because of a convention that email signatures and disclaimers usually come at the end of email messages after a line of one or more dashes - google is saving you from wasting time on that more-or-less useless info (which is potentially a tricky legal mistake by google - should they *really* be allowed to strip legal disclaimers???  It's not their email to change, and they don't have the owner (sender) permission to do that either...)